# undefined reference to `__imp_ ...' fix

Tags: c, dll, compilation, lib

I'm writing a code to run an ft2232HL interface convertor (USB to SPI in particular). All pre-installations are done with MSYS. While compiling the programme, I get this (compiling is done in cmd with gcc command)

> undefined reference to `__imp_SPI_GetNumChannels'

What might be the problem? As far as I see, there may be a problem with the process of linking the actual code of external libs to the programme.

The code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "C:/Users/Lev/Desktop/USB_to_SPI/lib/release/libftd2xx/ftd2xx.h"
#include "C:/Users/Lev/Desktop/USB_to_SPI/lib/release/include/libmpsse_spi.h"

int main(void) {
    DWORD channels;
    SPI_GetNumChannels(&channels);
    printf("The number of channels is: %lu", channels);
}
```

Comment: You need to link with the library that includes that function.  Add `-l libraryname` to your compile command line.

Comment: You mean gcc -l "libraryname"? In case there are several libs, should I put gcc -l "libname" -l "libname"?

Comment: If there's more than one then you add each one to the line. `gcc foo.c -o foo -lmpsse_spi -lsomethingelse`